# data.table column does not update as expected when new column values have different class

Tags: r, data.table

I am struggling to understand the following behaviour when I want to update a column which I had created before "by reference".

```r
library(data.table)
#> Warning: package 'data.table' was built under R version 3.6.1
set.seed(2)
mydt <- data.table(group = rep(letters[1:2], each = 5), date1 = as.Date(sample(10), origin = '1970-01-01'), date2 = as.Date(sample(10),origin = '1970-01-01'))

mydt[, diffdates := date1-date2] # creates column "diffdates"

mydt[, whichdate := date1[which.min(abs(date1-date2))], by ='group'] 
#whichdate is created in order to show what I would expect in the next step

mydt[, diffdates := date1[which.min(abs(date1-date2))], by ='group'] 
# diffdates is NOT updated in the way I want (should look like "whichdate").

mydt
#>     group      date1      date2 diffdates  whichdate
#>  1:     a 1970-01-06 1970-01-02    1 days 1970-01-02
#>  2:     a 1970-01-07 1970-01-04    1 days 1970-01-02
#>  3:     a 1970-01-10 1970-01-07    1 days 1970-01-02
#>  4:     a 1970-01-02 1970-01-03    1 days 1970-01-02
#>  5:     a 1970-01-11 1970-01-10    1 days 1970-01-02
#>  6:     b 1970-01-08 1970-01-11    3 days 1970-01-04
#>  7:     b 1970-01-05 1970-01-08    3 days 1970-01-04
#>  8:     b 1970-01-09 1970-01-06    3 days 1970-01-04
#>  9:     b 1970-01-04 1970-01-05    3 days 1970-01-04
#> 10:     b 1970-01-03 1970-01-09    3 days 1970-01-04
```

As a matter of fact, something is happening, but not quite the desired result. (I would expect the updated column to be the same as my "whichdate" column).
What I don't understand is that it works using simple functions, e.g.:

```
mtcars_dt <- as.data.table(mtcars)

mtcars_dt[, max_mpg := min(mpg), by = 'cyl'] 

mtcars_dt[, max_mpg := max(mpg), by = 'cyl'] #properly updates the previous column

head(mtcars_dt)
#>     mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb max_mpg
#> 1: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4    21.4
#> 2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4    21.4
#> 3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1    33.9
#> 4: 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1    21.4
#> 5: 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2    19.2
#> 6: 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1    21.4
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: What would your desired/expected output look like?

Comment: @Joost like the column `whichdate` which I have included in order to show the desired output. I have added this explanation in the question now

Comment: The help on `:= {data.table}` state it cannot perform grouping operations. Could that be relevant?

Comment: @markhogue no it works for the mtcars example.

Comment: Please see the **Details** section of `?":="`: "Unlike `<-` for data.frame, the (potentially large) LHS is not coerced to match the type of the (often small) RHS. _Instead the RHS is coerced to match the type of the LHS_ [your `Date` is coerced to `difftime`], if necessary. [...] The motivation for this is efficiency. It is best to get the column types correct up front and stick to them. Changing a column type is possible but deliberately harder: provide a whole column as the RHS."

Comment: Small example, similar to yours: `d <- data.table(x1 = as.difftime(1:2, units = "days"))`; `d[ , x2 := x1]`; Update x1: `d[ ,  x1 := Sys.Date()]`, `length(RHS) < length(LHS)` -> RHS is coerced to class of LHS. Update x2: `d[ , x2 := rep(Sys.Date(), .N)]` , `length(RHS) == length(LHS)`-> LHS is coerced to class of RHS - plonk!

Comment: To improve the agreement between my comment above and the help text ("provide a _whole column_ as the RHS"), I would replace `length(RHS) < length(LHS)` with `length(RHS) < nrow(d)`, and `length(RHS) == length(LHS)` with `length(RHS) == nrow(d)`.

Comment: As usual, you can get more information by setting `verbose = TRUE` (`d[ , x1 := Sys.Date(), verbose = TRUE]`; `d[ , x2 := rep(Sys.Date(), .N), verbose = TRUE]`).

Comment: @Henrik very interesting. Thanks many times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because data.table maintains the class of a column after the column is created. If you try to replace an existing column with a new vector of a different class it will either convert to the original class or give an error. Here `diffdates` is a difftime-classed object and you're attempting to replace it with a date-classed object.

One solution is to remove the column then add it back, as below.

```
mydt[, diffdates := NULL]
mydt[, diffdates := date1[which.min(abs(date1-date2))], by ='group']
```

Adding to this based on @Henrik's comment above, another way to change your column to a new class is to provide a vector of length `nrow(dt)` on the right-hand side of `:=`. Note: Even if the lengths in grouping add up to `nrow(dt)` this does not work, you have to give a vector of length `nrow(dt)` (and therefore this method for changing the class does not work when using `by`)

Example:

```
d <- data.table(a = rep(1:2, 2), b = 1:4)

d[, b := rep(Sys.Date(), .N), by = a][]
#    a     b
# 1: 1 18214
# 2: 2 18214
# 3: 1 18214
# 4: 2 18214
d[, b := Sys.Date()][]
#    a     b
# 1: 1 18214
# 2: 2 18214
# 3: 1 18214
# 4: 2 18214
d[, b := rep(Sys.Date(), .N)][]
#    a          b
# 1: 1 2019-11-14
# 2: 2 2019-11-14
# 3: 1 2019-11-14
# 4: 2 2019-11-14
```

Comment: Thanks. Interesting. Good to know.